# Inverse Dynamics Controller Drake

Tags: python, drake

I currently have an array of desired position vs. time of an object in my plant. I am using an inverse dynamics controller in order to drive the object to this desired position but I'm experiencing some difficulties. Here is how I am doing this:

1. I created the controller system

```
ID_cont = InverseDynamicsController(robot=controller_plant, kp=np.array([0.5]), ki=np.array([0.3]), kd=np.array([0.4]), has_reference_acceleration=False)
ID_controller = builder.AddSystem(ID_cont)
```

2. I got the controller input and output ports

```
    control_estimated_state_input_port = ID_controller.get_input_port(0)
    control_desired_state_input_port = ID_controller.get_input_port(1)
    control_output_port = ID_controller.get_output_port(0)
```

3. I added a constant state source (likely wrong to do) and a state interpolator

```
    constant_state_source = ConstantVectorSource(np.array([0.0]))
    builder.AddSystem(constant_state_source)
    position_to_state = StateInterpolatorWithDiscreteDerivative(controller_plant.num_positions(),
                                                                controller_plant.time_step())
    builder.AddSystem(position_to_state)
```

4. I wired the controller to the plant

```
    builder.Connect(constant_state_source.get_output_port(), position_to_state.get_input_port())
    builder.Connect(position_to_state.get_output_port(), control_desired_state_input_port)
    builder.Connect(plant.get_state_output_port(model_instance_1), control_estimated_state_input_port)
    builder.Connect(control_output_port, plant.get_actuation_input_port(model_instance_1))
```

5. Next, I am trying to create a while loop that advances the simulation and changes the 'constant vector source' so I can feed in my position vs. time values but I'm unsure if the reason this isn't working out is because this is the complete wrong approach or if this is the right approach but I just have a few things wrong

```
    diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
    sim_time_temp = diagram_context.get_time()
    time_step = 0.1

    while sim_time_temp < duration:
        ID_controller_context = diagram.GetMutableSubsystemContext(ID_controller, diagram_context)
        simulator.AdvanceTo(sim_time_temp)
        sim_time_temp = sim_time_temp + time_step
```

Comment: I don't see modification of the ConstantVectorSource value in the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

> 3. I added a constant state source (likely wrong to do) and a state interpolator

As you suspected, this is not the best way to go if you already have a desired sequence of positions and times that you want the system to track. Instead, you should use a [`TrajectorySource`](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.systems.primitives.html#pydrake.systems.primitives.TrajectorySource). Since you have a set of positions samples, `positions` (num_times x num_positions array), that you'd like the system to hit at specified `times` (num_times x 1 array), [`PiecewisePolynomial.CubicShapePreserving`](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.trajectories.html#pydrake.trajectories.PiecewisePolynomial.CubicShapePreserving) is a reasonable choice for building the trajectory.

```
desired_position_trajectory = PiecewisePolynomial.CubicShapePreserving(times, positions)
desired_state_source = TrajectorySource(desired_position_trajectory,
                                        output_derivative_order=1)
builder.AddSystem(desired_state_source)
```

The `output_derivative_order=1` argument makes `desired_state_source` output a [position, velocity] vector rather than just a position vector. You can connect `desired_state_source` directly to the controller, without an interpolator.

With this setup, you can advance the simulation all the way to `duration` without the need for a while loop.